# How to establish this inequality without using induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Given the Fibonacci sequence $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $\ldots$, $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1} $ for $n \geq 2$, how to derive, without using induction, the inequality $$ a_n < (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n $$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$?

I know how to establish the above inequality using induction.

Comment: Does using well-ordering not allowed too? What about Dedekind completeness of real number?

Comment: Gina, what if we do use well-ordering? And what is the Dedekind completeness of real numbers?

Comment: Using well-ordering is essentially induction in the reverse way: assuming a counterexample exist, then there must be a smallest counterexample. Using Dedekind completeness allow you to obtain an infimum of counterexample, which is easily seen to be minimum (ie. using well-ordering in a round about way)

Comment: Seeing as you defined the $a_n$ by induction it's going to be completely impossible to prove any non-trivial property of them without using induction in some form or other. Maybe you're trying to rule out one particular induction proof.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what is meant by *proof without using induction*. One formalization of this I could imagine would be asking for proof using [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) with the exception of induction axioms. But there are even problems with formulating the claim in this setting. (The sequence would be not uniquely determined.) If you would require to be true for every such sequence, then the claim would probably not be true in all models.

Answer (score 1):

The fibbonacci numbers have a [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression): $a_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1} - \left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right]$.

Since $\left|\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right| < 1$, we have $-1 < \left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1} < 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Can you figure out what to do from here?

Comment: JimmyK4542, how to derive this closed form?

Comment: By induction, Saaqib.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud : Can be derived from characteristic equation or by using generating function.

Comment: I suspect if you inspect the characteristic equation and generating function methods closely enough, you'll find induction lurking there.

Answer (score 1):

We may as well let the (Fibonacci) sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ begin with $a_0=1$. Put ${1+\sqrt{5}\over2}=:\phi$ and  consider the auxiliary sequence
$$b_n:=1-{a_n\over\phi^n}\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
We have to show that  $b_n>0$ for all $n\geq1$.

*Proof.* One has $b_0=0$; then $\phi>1=a_1$ implies $b_1>0$. Finally it is easily verified that the $b_n$ satisfy the recursion
$$b_n={b_{n-1}\over\phi}+{b_{n-2}\over\phi^2}\qquad(n\geq2)\ ,$$
so that the claim follows by inspection.

Comment: $a_0$ has not been defined; for consistency with the recursion, we'd take $a_0=1$, but then $b_0=0$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thank you. I had missed that $a_2=2$ (and not the usual $1$).